# $$, \[ \] and equation environment alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, inline

I'm using `scrreprt` class and I'm having troubles with different behavior of `$$` and `\[ \]`-written equations and equation environment. The problem is that alignment is not the same: `$$` equations are centered while equations in equation environment are left aligned.

For example, the following code

```
Equations:
\begin{equation}\label{nelineq}
f(x)=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}\label{nelineq}
f(x)=0
\end{equation*}
$$
f(x)=0
$$
\[ f(x)=0 \]
```

produces
[image: output]

I would like to make all three usages consistent (not yet sure if centered or left aligned).

The question is, how to **permanently change default alignments** for all three cases? But without use of `align` or similar environments (dont want to edit all existing equations).

I know that `$$` is deprecated, but what about other two methods?

Comment: Which options did you pass to the class call?

Comment: You have apparently used the `fleqn` option and so all LaTeX environments shown in your image are flush left already. `$$` is not latex syntax and does its own thing.

Comment: `$$` is not _deprecated_ it just doesn't work, the most obvious and well documented, aspect of that is that it does not obey `fleqn` option.

Comment: Ok, the `fleqn` option was turned on.`\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath} % Math environments and more by the AMS 
 \usepackage{amsmath}`. Now, at least i can center all equations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have apparently used the `fleqn` option and so all LaTeX environments shown in your image are flush left.

`$$` is not latex syntax and does its own thing, it is not *deprecated* it just doesn't work, the most obvious and well documented, aspect of that is that it does not obey `fleqn` option.

If the class (or user) doesn't specify `fleqn` then the LaTeX environments will center display math.